# Angular 2 Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may on strict mode functions or the arguments objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a problem in Angular 2, I know this is a recurring problem, but I could not find the resolution. I made a service which is called from another Component, is no problem there.

The problem was in the service, I'm trying to make a http POST and get and error:

> [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.remoteFunction**

[error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Olc.png)
[complete error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n81IZ.png)

Apparently the error is given in handleErrorObservable, because the post is not executed either, looking at the network tab in Chrome I do not see any POST call to the API.

Here my service Code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { User } from "./user";
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Headers  } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
     usersUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/TrabajoPromocion/users/';  
    constructor(private http:Http) { }
 
    addBookWithObservable( ): Observable<User> { 
        let body = JSON.stringify({   
            "fullname": "a",
            "username": "h",
            "password": "3",
            "email": "33"
        }); 
        
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        console.log('3');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
         return this.http.post(this.usersUrl, body, options)
                       .map(this.extractData)
                       .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);             
    }
     
    private extractData(res: Response) { 
        let body = res.json();
            return body || {};
    }

    private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) { 
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Thanks to all, any help is welcome.

Comment: http is being deprecated. Try using http client. before everything try to make a post call using POSTMAN or any other clients and see if you are getting the response.

Comment: Yes, its tested with postman and works well. Now, I need to make the request with Angular service.

Comment: why are you stringifying the body for the POST-request? you should pass a JS-object to it

Comment: Yes, but now I removed it, just to be sure that that was not part of the problem.

Comment: I don't see the part where you `subscribe` to the Observable

Comment: @BorisLobanov I'm calling this method from another component. on a form submit,                                                                               
       onSubmit() { 
        console.log(this.model); 
        //this.submitted = true; 
          
       this.registerService.addBookWithObservable( );
  
    }

Comment: I still don't see the subscribe call. An Observable can't be executed without the subscribe call. Can you post the code where you are calling it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on what I've seen I can assume that the reason your request is not being sent is that you don't call `.subscribe` anywhere on you observable. Observables are just functions and they are not executed until you call them. That's what subscribe does - calls the functions and all the operators are then executed as well.

What you are seeing in the developers tools is not the actual error from the request, it's the message to you that you cannot view the arguments or the caller, or the callee of the function in developer's tools.

So the solution is to simply add the `subscribe` call (or async pipe would also do the job).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that! Now is solved, that but a I have an error the post is making to http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found). But this is another issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool, happy to help!